# jQuery validate assigning rules to elements in multiple forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to assign a rule to a field on a form from the validation of another form. The form I am validating is in a modal and is adding to the form in the main page (underneath). Those elements that it adds need to be checked with rules in the form underneath.

So, I want the form in the modal to do stuff like this:

```
$('#modal_form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // Add elements

        // Add rules to the new elements to be processed by the other form
        $('#element_I_add_to_form_below_modal').rules('add', {
                run_this_rule: true
        });
   }
});
```

What can work out is how to tell the rule to apply to the validation of the form on the form underneath this one.

Something like:

```
 var master_form = document.forms.parent_form;  
 var new_element = $('#new_element');
 master_form.new_element.rules('add', {
    run_this_rule: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was elementary.

I called a function in the script on the main page that did the rules assignment at the end of the current forms validation process.

So, the modal form calls a function:

```
$('#modal_form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // Add elements

        add_to_main_form('element_I_add_to_form_below_modal');
    }
});
```

And a script in the main page adds the rule to the correct form:

```
function  add_to_main_form(name){
    // Add rules to the new elements to be processed by the other form
    $('#' + name).rules('add', {
            run_this_rule: true
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear and show the code that solved this problem.  BTW - The `.validate()` method is not the "validation process"... it's the *initialization* process.